# Encode Double Quotes in Razor expression in View

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I have the following expression on an ASP.NET Core Razor view:

```
<a href="@(Options.CurrentValue.Applications.First(x => x.Name == "Spa").Url)">
```

When I build it I get the error:

```
A space or line break was encountered after the "@" character.  Only valid identifiers, keywords, comments, "(" and "{" are valid at the start of a code block and they must occur immediately following "@" with no space in between.
```

I added the parenthesis after the @ because I have double quotes in my code.

How to solve this?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this code. You don't have a line break or space after the `@` here. Is there perhaps a non-printable character there?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error when space, tab (or any special char) exists after @. Try to revise code with CTRL + E, S (in VS) to display all special characters.

As a variant, you can replace double quotes with single quotes:

```
<a href='@Options.CurrentValue.Applications.First(x => x.Name == "Spa").Url'>
```